# Comparing one array to another and create a new array based on the differences

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

Had my earlier question closed because I left out an important detail.

Say I have the following two Arrays

```
const salesDates = ['2021/06/30','2021/07/01','2021/07/02','2021/07/03','2021/07/04','2021/07/05','2021/07/06']
```

and

```
const jsonSalesData = [
         {date: '2021/07/01', company: 'ABC', sales: '32460'},
         {date: '2021/07/02', company: 'ABC', sales: '28165'},
         {date: '2021/07/03', company: 'ABC', sales: '31546'},
         {date: '2021/07/04', company: 'ABC', sales: '12654'},
         {date: '2021/07/05', company: 'ABC', sales: '26457'},
         {date: '2021/07/06', company: 'ABC', sales: '20351'},
         {date: '2021/07/07', company: 'ABC', sales: '56404'},
]
```

What I need to do is

1. Return the objects from `jsonSalesData` if the `date` in `jsonSalesData` matches the `salesDates` array
2. If there is a date in `salesDates` that is not in `jsonSalesData` add an object to the `jsonSalesData` with that `date` and set the `sales` to `0`.

**Desired Output**

```
[
{date: '2021/06/30', company: 'ABC', sales: '0'},
{date: '2021/07/01', company: 'ABC', sales: '32460'},
{date: '2021/07/02', company: 'ABC', sales: '28165'},
{date: '2021/07/03', company: 'ABC', sales: '31546'},
{date: '2021/07/04', company: 'ABC', sales: '12654'},
{date: '2021/07/05', company: 'ABC', sales: '26457'},
{date: '2021/07/06', company: 'ABC', sales: '20351'},
]
```

*notice the addition of the 1st object and the exclusion of the last object*

I've tried to use `forEach` but it only accomplishes #1 (returns the dates in `jsonSalesData` which match to `salesDates`). It doesn't add the object if there is no match.

```
const n = [];
jsonSalesData.forEach(e => {
    if (salesDates.includes(e.date)){ 
      n.push(e);
  }
})
console.log(n);
```

I've also tried nested loops, but I can't seem to figure it out. Here's what I did for those:

```
    for (let i = 0; i < jsonSalesData.length; i++){
        for (let j = 0; j < salesData.length; j++){     
        if (jsonSalesData[i].date === salesData[j]){
console.log(jsonSalesData[i].company,jsonSalesData[i].date,jsonSalesData[i].sales)
        }
    
      }
    }
```

Same issues with `map` and `filter` -- I can't seem to look back at `salesData` and add an object back to `jsonSalesData` if something in `salesData` doesn't exist in `jsonSalesData`

Comment: How do you know the company for 6/30?

Comment: Because there is a 2021/06/30 date in `salesDates` but not a 2021/06/30 in `jsonSalesData`. Therefore, it was added with a 0 sales.

Comment: salesDates.map(date => jsonSalesData.find(row=> row.date===date) || { date, sales: 0 });

Comment: How do you know that the company is ABC for 6/30?

Comment: the company is not necessary to be considered not but I'd like but I'd like to retain that in the newly generated array

Comment: Show us what you have tried, or where you are stuck. SO is not a coding service. You can visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @loop offered a good suggestion so long as there is only one element for each date in `jsonSalesData`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you don't care about adding the company name arbitrarily, you could do something like this

```js
const salesDates = ['2021/06/30','2021/07/01','2021/07/02','2021/07/03','2021/07/04','2021/07/05','2021/07/06']
 
const jsonSalesData = [
         {date: '2021/07/01', company: 'ABC', sales: '32460'},
         {date: '2021/07/02', company: 'ABC', sales: '28165'},
         {date: '2021/07/03', company: 'ABC', sales: '31546'},
         {date: '2021/07/04', company: 'ABC', sales: '12654'},
         {date: '2021/07/05', company: 'ABC', sales: '26457'},
         {date: '2021/07/06', company: 'ABC', sales: '20351'},
         {date: '2021/07/07', company: 'ABC', sales: '56404'},
]

let updatedSalesData = salesDates.map(date => jsonSalesData.find(item=> item.date==date) || { date, company: 'ABC', sales: '0' }); 

console.log(updatedSalesData)
```